# What's the correct way to render Asciidoc HTML in Gatsby?

Tags: gatsby, asciidoc, gatsby-plugin

I'm following the Gatsby tutorial, but instead of using the MDX transformer, I'd like to use the officially-supported Asciidoc one (gatsby-transformer-asciidoc). In the part 6 of tutorial, a page query is used to retrieve the correct content, and then render it to a page. To get hold of the actual content, the tutorial says it "[will be passed as a `children` prop to the page component](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/tutorial/getting-started/part-6/#:%7E:text=The%20actual%20MDX%20content%2C%20ready%20to%20render%2C%20will%20be%20passed%20as%20a%20children%20prop%20to%20the%20page%20component)".

However, with the gatsby-transformer-asciidoc plugin, that doesn't appear to be the case. Is there some convention that transformer plugins have to follow for their content to be passed through as `children` when a page query executes? And is gatsby-transformer-asciidoc not following it?

As a workaround, the content itself is available in the GraphQL query as `html`. I'm setting that on a JSX element with `dangerouslySetInnerHtml`, which seems to work, but it feels like I'm going about it the wrong way. Any advice?

Here's the GraphQL page query I'm using, if its helpful:

```
  query GetAsciidoc($id: String) {
    asciidoc(id: {eq: $id}) {
      document {
        title
      }
      pageAttributes {
        date
      }
      html
    }
  }
```